# How to compare between two methods of multivariate to filling NA

Tags: scikit-learn, missing-data, data-imputation, lasso

In the Titanic dataset, I performed two methods to fill Age NA.
The first one is regression using Lasso:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
AgefillnaModel=Lasso(copy_X=False)
AgefillnaModel_X.dropna(inplace=True)
y=DF.Age.dropna(inplace=False)
AgefillnaModel.fit(AgefillnaModel_X,y)
DF.loc[ageNaIn,'Age']=AgefillnaModel.predict(DF.loc[ageNaIn,AgefillnaModel_X.columns])
```

and the second method is using `IterativeImputer()` from `scikit-learn.impute`.

```
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
# Setting the random_state argument for reproducibility
imputer = IterativeImputer(random_state=42)
imputed = imputer.fit_transform(DF)
df_imputed = pd.DataFrame(imputed, columns=DF.columns)
round(df_imputed, 2)
```

Now, how can I decide which one is better?

Here is the result of scattered Age vs Sex:

[image]

Comment: What method is it using to perform the imputation in the 2 examples?

Comment: as i mentioned above this is the exat code i used ,scikit user guide for `IterativeImputer` [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#iterative-imputer)

Answer (score 0):

You don't at this stage. Train a few models with each method and compare.

Comment: you mean it is not  significant  at this stage how i fill missing value, so i should move to build  a model, thanks

Comment: In addition, you may find cases where one method works better for (say) linear model, while another works better for RF. Never know till you try.

Comment: @Icrmorin - this is indeed the answer - one cannot decide what imputation method (or in general, any preprocessing pipeline) is better until you apply the processed data to some usage (e.g. classification). Please revise.